# Does there exist any protocol which follows only request model?

Tags: http, servlets, https, smtp, protocols

HTTP follows the [request-response model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response), i.e. for every request from a client there will be a response from the server.

Does there exist any protocol that follows only **request** model (there will be only requests from client)?

I know SMTP. Can I consider SMTP as request only model because we are sending the mail but not receiving any response from server?

If there exists any other such protocol, please explain about it. I googled it but didn't find any answer related to my specific query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I consider SMTP as request only model because we are sending the mail but not receiving any response from server?

No, because for every command the client sends to the SMTP server, the client gets a response. SMTP is a lot more *chattier* than HTTP. Just to send a single email, an SMTP server and a client communicate with each other at least 5 times.

This is how SMTP works:

```
Client: EHLO yourdomain.com
Server: 250 smtp.gmail.com

Client: MAIL FROM: you@yourdomain.com
Server: 250 Ok

Client: RCPT TO: someone@gmail.com
Server: 250 Ok

Client: DATA
Server: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>

Client: Hey how are you?
Client: .
Server: 250 Ok

Client: QUIT
Server: 221 smtp.gmail.com Closing connection. Goodbye!
```

As you can see, this is also a request-response protocol.

But the Wikipedia page that you linked says that SMTP is a one-way protocol, which is wrong.

---

> Does there exist any protocol that follows only request model (there will be only requests from client)?

Most protocols are there for **exchanging** data, that is why they follow the request-response model. The client wants to see a page, so he requests it from the server and then the server sends the page in response. The data is being exchanged between the server and the client.

But if you want you can write a protocol which is one way only.